# Where to find eventfd_write documentation?

Tags: c, linux, glibc, epoll, centos6

Is there a detailed documentation for eventfd_write?

man eventfd_write brings up the manpage of eventfd.  On that manpage, it mentions eventfd_write() is offered by glibc.

Google only indexed 6 pages of entire gnu's site for eventfd_write.  None of them is related to the documentation.

Any idea where I can find it?

P.S. Another side question (but sort of related): is there a mailing list to ask non-distribution specific questions about glibc? I only see the point of contacts for distribution specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of detailed documentation are you looking for? I asked Google for "eventfd", the first hit was a [Linux man-pages website](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html), and the online man page says

> The GNU C library defines an additional type, and two functions that
>   attempt to abstract some of the details of reading and writing on an
>   eventfd file descriptor:
>
> ```
>     typedef uint64_t eventfd_t;
>
>     int eventfd_read(int fd, eventfd_t *value);
>     int eventfd_write(int fd, eventfd_t value);
> ```
>
> The functions perform the read and write operations on an eventfd
>   file descriptor, returning 0 if the correct number of bytes was
>   transferred, or -1 otherwise.

Basically, the `eventfd_write()` function takes a file descriptor (which must have been obtained via a call to `eventfd()`), and a 64-bit unsigned integer, writes the 64-bit unsigned integer to the file descriptor, and returns either `0` for success, or `-1` for failure.

How is that not detailed enough?

Comment: Looking for the list of reason why eventfd_read/write() return -1.